# Try-Expect block not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am a novice at programming.
The basic idea is, when user inputs data, the code should check the data. If the data is not numerical. Instead of showing valueerror, it should show "Please enter only numbers!" message.

```
    number1 = int(input("Enter "))
    try:
        temp = number1/1
    except ValueError:
        msg = "Please enter only numbers!"
        print(msg)
```

But the code is not working as intended and showing this 
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
number1 = int(input("Enter "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aa'
```

Please let me know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `try` only handles errors that happen *inside the `try`*.

Comment: I am a novice at programming. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

`try` catches error only inside its scope, the line which threw the error in your code is not in `try` block, do this:

```
try:
    number1 = int(input("Enter "))
    temp = number1/1
except ValueError:
    msg = "Please enter only numbers!"
    print(msg)
```